# A sequence of numbers should be displayed, but only the last one appears

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a container that displays a number. I want after i click on the Shuffle-Button, that 10 Numbers are displayed each after 1000 milliseconds.
Unfortunately only the last generated number is displayed after 10 second.

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
      setState(() {
        randomNum = Random().nextInt(19) + 1;
      });
      sleep(Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
    }
  },
  child: const Text('Shuffle')),
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `sleep` to delay in a flutter application (in general).

`sleep()` blocks the current isolate (roughly analogous to a thread). This means that while the `sleep()` is happening, nothing else on that isolate can happen. In a flutter application, this also means will not update until the `sleep()` finishes.

Instead, you can use `Future.delayed(duration)` to *asynchonously* wait for a duration. Instead of stopping all execution on the current isolate, `Future.delayed` allows things to happen in the background (including UI updates), and resumes after the duration has elapsed.

In order actually wait for the duration, you should make your function `async`, which lets you use the `await` keyword to actually wait for that time. For example:

```dart
onPressed: () async {  // mark function as async to allow await
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setState(() { ... });  // set randomNum
  }
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));  // notice the await keyword
}
```

This will allow Flutter to repaint the UI while your function is running.

P.S.
If you use the `supercharged` package, you can use:

```dart
await 1.seconds.delay;
```

instead of

```dart
await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.